# Python classes: String does not get checked properly

Tags: python, class, oop

so I want to check a string twice that is used while instantiating an object. First check if it is a string and then the contents of the string. Also I'd like to raise two different kinds of errors for this:

```
class myObj:
    def __init__(self, obj_id):
        self._obj_id = obj_id

    @property
    def obj_id(self):
        return self._obj_id

    @obj_id.setter
    def obj_id(self, obj_id):
        if not type(obj_id) == str:
            raise TypeError("The obj_id needs to be a string")
        try:
            int(obj_id)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("The obj_id needs to be an unsigned Integer-like number (e.g. 5837829)")

        self._obj_id = obj_id
```

The test for string works just fine, however the try/except-expression in which I try to cast to int does not get touched.

If I run thi
s and instantiate that object by:

```
my_object = myObj("asdf")
print(my_object.obj_id)
```

I get `asdf`.
However, I expected something more like this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'
```

My initial guess is that the try/except expression does not get executed, however I don't understand why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are assigning to `self._obj_id`, which won't invoke the setter method. You need to assign to `self.obj_id`.

This would result in:

```
class myObj:
    def __init__(self, obj_id):
        self.obj_id = obj_id

    @property
    def obj_id(self):
        return self._obj_id

    @obj_id.setter
    def obj_id(self, obj_id):
        if not type(obj_id) == str:
            raise TypeError("The obj_id needs to be a string")
        try:
            int(obj_id)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("The obj_id needs to be an unsigned Integer-like number (e.g. 5837829)")

        self._obj_id = obj_id
```

Comment: Got me, thanks! However, now I get this: RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: @goetzmoritz I didn't get that when I changed the assignment in the constructor. Did you also change the assignment in the setter method? That's not required and would result in infinite recursion (the setter would call the setter, etc).

Comment: What assignment in the setter do you actually mean? I tried to assign the argument obj_id to _obj_id also in the setter. But it keeps recursing.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the full source I used (which works). The only change is `self.obj_id = obj_id` in the constructor.

Comment: works. The other answer is also good, but you were first and you align to the code provided. Thanks! However, I still need some minutes to actually understand why this is. happening...

Answer (score 1):

The below should work for you

```
class IntHolder:
    def __init__(self, obj_id):
        self._validate(obj_id)
        self._obj_id = obj_id

    @property
    def obj_id(self):
        return self._obj_id

    @obj_id.setter
    def obj_id(self, obj_id):
        self._validate(obj_id)
        self._obj_id = obj_id

    @staticmethod
    def _validate(obj_id: str):
        if not type(obj_id) == str:
            raise TypeError("The obj_id needs to be a string")
        try:
            int(obj_id)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("The obj_id needs to be an unsigned Integer-like number (e.g. 5837829)")
```

Comment: Your answer is great and I'd like to accept it as it is more comprehensive. However, the other one was first and somewhat aligns to the code provided. Your answer is great though and I'll adept to that, thank you!